# Using npm on a machine without internet access, but with lots of modules in mutiple node_modules directorties

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, local-node-modules

I would like to create a new npm project with a few modules on a machine without internet access.

This machine has various older projects each with a `node_modules` folder with lots of modules in there.

Can I somehow tell `npm` to use all these modules to create the new project instead of going out to the internet?

When I just issue

```
$ npm install browser-sync gulp gulp-sass
```

npm obviously tries to download these modules from the internet instead of gathering them from the various `node_modules` directories on the machine where the modules already exist!

Comment: Do you have _all_ dependencies and all of _their_ dependencies, and so on? It's definitely theoretically possible to create the node_modules tree by hand, but it'll be an awful lot of work, and you'll have to rm your package-lock.json or yarn.lock. You can get a list of all required packages with `grep '"node_modules/' package-lock.json` in your project.

Comment: You could also try setting `NODE_PATH` to all the various `node_modules` directories (separated by a colon, like PATH, or semicolon on Windows). I have no idea if that will work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I guess I have all dependencies. Just was hoping npm can do the copying of the modules plus the necessary additions to the `package.json` for me -- as it does when installing over the internet.

Comment: No easy way to make that happen, no. If you have remote or physical access, you could always simply `npm i` on a computer that has outside internet access, ZIP it up, and get it to that machine.